# Terraform give IAM access to specific folder only in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam

How can I create an IAM user using terraform with access to one folder in s3

I found a lot of answers that give access to the entire bucket but I want access to one folder only

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "username-s3-access" {
  name   = "username-s3-access"
  path   = "/"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.username-s3-access.json
}


resource "aws_iam_user" "username-s3-access" {
  name = "username-s3-access"
  path = "/machine/"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "username-s3-access" {
  user       = aws_iam_user.username-s3-access.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.username-s3-access.arn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution based on this official documentation in AWS site https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-folder-user-access/

**This code will give full assess to one folder in the bucket**

scroll down to find the code for **readonly access** to one folder

Note: change the **bucket_arn** and the **folder_name**

```
variable "bucket_arn" {
  type = string
  default = "bucket_arn" 
}

variable "folder_name" {
  type = string
  default = "s3_folder_name"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "username-s3-access" {
  statement {
    sid       = "AllowUserToSeeBuckets"
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]

    actions = [
      "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid       = "AllowBucketListing"
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = [ var.bucket_arn ]
    actions   = ["s3:ListBucket"]
  }

  statement {
    sid       = "AllowFolderListing"
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = [ var.bucket_arn ]
    actions   = ["s3:ListBucket"]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:prefix"

      values = [
        "",
        "${var.folder_name}"
      ]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:delimiter"
      values   = ["/"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    sid       = "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder"
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["${var.bucket_arn}/${var.folder_name}/*"]
    actions   = ["s3:*"]
  }
}


resource "aws_iam_policy" "username-s3-access" {
  name   = "username-s3-access"
  path   = "/"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.username-s3-access.json
}


resource "aws_iam_user" "username-s3-access" {
  name = "username-s3-access"
  path = "/machine/"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "username-s3-access" {
  user       = aws_iam_user.username-s3-access.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.username-s3-access.arn
}
```

if you want to give read only access to the folder then replace the last statement

```
statement {
    sid       = "AllowReadOnlyInUserFolder"
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = ["${var.bucket_name}/${var.folder_name}/*"]
    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
    ]
  }
```